# have problem in image control c#.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi
i  have a problem with my image control that is when i upload an image it shows that image but when i update it, its shows old image while updates in data base i think it gets image from cache is there any technique to handle this issue kindly tell me.

```
Image1.ImageUrl = populatedata.ResultSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][12].ToString();
string file_ext = Path.GetFileName(Image1.ImageUrl);
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/EmpImages/" + file_ext;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code sample. I don't understand why you are setting your Image1.ImageUrl twice?

I don't think it could be a caching issue. What you need to do make a call to the database (rebind) to retrieve the new image url after a new image upload has happened.

Comment: i m binding it with data base and records updates in data base but when i show it retrieves old image